# why do we make head a null in singly linked list?

Tags: data-structures, nodes, singly-linked-list

Why is that when we try to make a singly linked list we make the Head NULL in the class and not make the Next of the Head as Null . In the functions regarding the linked lists why do we make the Next of the nodes Null and not make the Node Null?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please Explain it .

Comment: Why do we make Head=Null and not Head->next=Null?

Comment: So that you can check whether the list is empty, by checking whether `head==null`. You can only set `head->next=null` if there's already a first element that head points to.

Comment: The head is by definition the first element in the list. A list with no elements does not have a first element.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid waste. A list node is designed to store an element inside of it. Imagine if we had an empty list in your suggested scenario, where `*` denotes the head of the list. We would start with:

```
[*???]->NULL
```

Where `???` would just be some dummy variable for an unused element. We're already wasting a list node when we could simply do this:

```
*NULL
```

Likewise if we examine a non-empty list, we might have with your case:

```
[*123]->[456]->[789]->[???]->NULL
```

... when we could simply have:

```
[*123]->[456]->[789]->NULL
```

Of course you could augment this to overwrite this dummy variable when the list size goes from 0 to 1, but now that involves additional branching and so forth and we end up getting more complex instructions and processing overhead.

So there's really little to be gained by doing this, and potentially a lot to be lost.

> In the functions regarding the linked lists why do we make the Next of
>   the nodes Null and not make the Node Null?

I didn't quite understand this part. If we're talking about inserting a new node to a list, for example, we might have this:

```
[new node: 456]->???      [*123]->NULL
```

We then make it point to the head:

```
[new node: 456]->[*123]->NULL
```

... and then make the head point to the new node.

```
[*456]->[123]->NULL
```

So there should typically not be times where you're setting the next pointer of a node to null, unless it's to the head which happens to be null, or in response to removing a tail.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is when we display the content of the linked list in reverse order, we need to make sure that we have a certain condition by which we can verify when to stop during iteration of the linked list. Here is quick example.

```
function displayReverse() {
var currNode = this.head;
currNode = this.findLast();

while (!(currNode.previous === null)) {
    print(currNode.element);
    currNode = currNode.previous;
}
```

}